# Retrieve hash KEY from hash VALUE (in Ruby)

Tags: ruby, sockets, data-structures, hash, key

I'm trying to set up a server to play a game of war for an assignment.  I think I've got the sockets and players in a hash, where the keys are my sockets and the players are my values.

Now it's all well and good that I only write one retrieve function for the client class because they only need to pull from the server, but I need to be specific about from which client to take input, but I cannot figure out how to get a hash KEY from a hash VALUE in my program.

Mudasobwa, the test I'm trying to get to pass is the

```
def test_server_capture_output_from_client
```

at the bottom.  Thanks, this is really bugging me.

```
#SERVER CLASS -- Server starts up a TCP, and starts up the game and players and deal the cards
#SERVER CLASS -- Server starts up a TCP, and starts up the game and players and deal the cards
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'socket'
require_relative 'WarGame_Class.rb'
require_relative 'ModifiedPlayer_Class.rb'
require_relative 'DeckClass.rb'

class WarServer

    def initialize(host, port)  
        @socket_server = TCPServer.new(host, port)
        @players = [Player.new, Player.new]
        @deck = CardDeck.new
        @deck.deal_cards(@players[0].cards, @players[1].cards)
        game = WarGame.new
        @clients = {} # keys are sockets, values are players

    end

    def read_client_keys(keys)
        @clients.key[keys]
    end

    def close
        @socket_server.close
    end


    def capture_input(player)   ##input client to get what they wrote
        @input = @clients.keys[0].read_nonblock(1000) # arbitrary max number of bytes

    end

    def accept_client
        #Hash here to link client to player? (or game?)
        client = @socket_server.accept
        @clients[client] = @players[@clients.size]
    #   puts "clients key 0: #{@clients.keys[0]}"
        puts
    #   puts "clients values: #{@clients.values}"
        if @clients.size == 2
            start_game#####################!!!! Starts game if two clients  can put client messages in start game
        end
    end


    def start_game  ##############!!!
        @clients.keys[0].puts  "Welcome to War.  Please press enter to play your card"
        @clients.keys[1].puts  "Welcome to War.  Please press enter to play your card"

    end

end

class MockWarClient
    def initialize
        @socket = TCPSocket.new('localhost', 2012)
    end

    def output
        @output 
    end

    def capture_output  #need to add (socket)?  How else read from specific socket?
        @output = @socket.read_nonblock(1000) # arbitrary max number of bytes
    rescue
        @output = "capture_output error."
    end

    def capture_input

    end
end

class WarServerTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase


    def setup   #This would be like our INITIALIZE Function
        #anything is available through out all tests (i.e., instance vars)
        @war_server = WarServer.new('localhost', 2012)
    end


    def teardown
        @war_server.close
    end


    def test_have_1_port_listening


        socket_1 = TCPSocket.open('localhost', 2012)
        pass('connection in place')

        rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
        flunk('Port 1 error 1st test')


    end

    def test_connecting_two_clients 
            client_1 = MockWarClient.new
            @war_server.accept_client

            client_2 = MockWarClient.new
            @war_server.accept_client

            client_1.capture_output
            refute(client_1.output.empty?)

            #client2.capture_output
            #refute(client_2.output.empty?)
    end


    def test_server_capture_output_from_client
        client_1 = MockWarClient.new
        @war_server.accept_client

        client_2 = MockWarClient.new
        @war_server.accept_client

        #can output @war_server.read_client_keys, though, if I take out the argument to pass in.
        puts "Test_Server_output @client keys #{@war_server.read_client_keys(player)}" #cient_1?

        @warserver.capture_input
        refute(@war_server.input.empty)
    end    
end
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Could you more precisely explain the problem of retrieving of the sockets?

Comment: I'm a new programmer, and I'm having some trouble doing that.  My sockets should be my key values in my hash, I think, but I am having trouble getting them so I can read data sent from a specific socket.

Comment: just get them as array: `array = @clients.keys` that returns `=> [<Socket1>,<Socket2>, etc...]`, then use `array[ 0 ]` etc

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  That does work in irb, but for the life of me I can't call a specific socket.  I have 2, so I'm going to need to read from each (I think).  I can write a reader def and output the entire clients hash, but I can't get just a key to read from the socket.  I'll post my code below

Comment: @majioa
In fact even if I just make my reader def an argument I just get the 0 for 1 error.

like this:

       def read_client_keys
      @clients.key[0]
 end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, there is a `Hash#key` [method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-key) to retrieve a key by value:

```
h = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2}
puts h.key(2)
# ⇒ 'b'
```

In your case it seems to be sufficient. But aware of situation when there might be same values for different keys:

```
h = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 1}
puts h.key(1)
# ⇒ 'c'
```

Here you got the *last* key for this value. Whether you suspect same values for different keys, you’re likely to use either `Hash#keys` [method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-keys) or `Hash#each` iterator and handle the iteration manually.

For instance, to retrieve the keys for the given value as an array:

```
h = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 1}
puts h.select { |k,v| v == 1}.keys
# ⇒ ['a', 'c']
```

Comment: I got that part down, but I guess my problem is even more of how to access the key in the program.  I included my code so you could see it.  Even if I try to just puts it, I can write the reader for the whole hash but can't get a specific value out.

Comment: Excuse me, I can’t figure out what’s your problem. Just use `@client.key(player)` to retrieve the socket by player and `@client[socket]` to retrieve the player by socket.